# Data values passed from json is not recognized in CI Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This code should be working fine, as far as i can tell but for some reason it's not working. Can somebody please help me?!! T_T

js script:

```
$.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>/folder_name_ajax/unit_vacancy',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{unit_id:unit_id, unit_landlord_id:unit_landlord_id, unit_stat:unit_stat},

            beforeSend: function(){ 

            },
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log(response);
                alert('Unit status successfully updated.');
            }

        });
```

Controller:

```
function unit_vacancy()
{
    $this->load->model('modelAjax');

    $unit_id            = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('unit_id'));      
    $unit_landlord_id   = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('unit_landlord_id'));
    $unit_stat          = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('unit_stat'));
    $xplod_stat         = explode('-',$unit_stat);

    $this->modelAjax->update_unit_vacancy();

}
```

Model:

```
function update_unit_vacancy()
{
    $unit_id            = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('unit_id'));      
    $unit_landlord_id   = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('unit_landlord_id'));
    $unit_stat          = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('unit_stat'));
    $xplod_stat         = explode('-',$unit_stat);

    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS count FROM ".TBL_PREFIX."".UNIT_VACANT_TBL." WHERE unit_id = '$unit_id' ");
    $count = $result->num_rows();

    if($count == 0)
    {
        $result = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".TBL_PREFIX."".UNIT_VACANT_TBL."
                                    (
                                        unit_id,
                                        landlord_id,
                                        status
                                    )
                                    VALUES
                                    (
                                        '$unit_id',
                                        '$unit_landlord_id',
                                        'insert'
                                    )
                                     ");

    }
    else
    {
        $result = $this->db->query("UPDATE ".TBL_PREFIX."".UNIT_VACANT_TBL." 
                                    SET 
                                        status = 'update'
                                    WHERE 
                                        unit_id = '$unit_id' 
                                  ");
    }
}
```

I can't seem to understand what i did wrong here!!!

Comment: check your console for any errors.Also `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);` in your pfp function to check what is comming via request

Comment: nothing...my controller can't seem to accept the values i passed from json

Answer (score 1):

You are not `echo(ing)` anything in your controller as i see.? Where is your `json`? Is your `update_unit_vacancy()` returning the `json`? If `yes` then `echo` it.

```
 echo $this->modelAjax->update_unit_vacancy();
```

And check your console too for the response of the ajax. Would recomment you one more thing though, change the below line:

```
url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/rentdaddy_ajax/unit_vacancy',
```